# Simple Object-Oriented Cat has not been declared

Tags: c++

Here is a video i made with visuals of my issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqvQivVfAdI

I am following an online tutorial to learn C++.  Everything has been going great so far. I am using code::blocks and the person teaching is using Eclipse.

I have this specific code he told me to write, and it isn't working with code::blocks. I'm getting an error in `Cat.cpp`:

> 'Cat' has not been declared

Is there something I have to do differently since I am in code::blocks?

His video, if interested...

Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Cat cat1;

    cat1.speak();
    cat1.jump();

    return 0;
}
```

Cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H_INCLUDED
#define CAT_H_INCLUDED

class Cat{
public:
    void speak();
    void jump();
};

#endif // CAT_H_INCLUDED'
```

Cat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

/*Error on this line*/
void Cat::speak(){
    cout << "Meouwwww1!!! " << endl;
}

/*probably on this on too */
void Cat::jump(){
    cout << "Jumping to top of bookcase1" << endl;
}











#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
```

code put together

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H



 class Cat
 {
 public:
    Cat();

         void speak();

     private:
 };

 #endif // CAT_H


 void Cat::speak()
 {
    cout << "Meouwww2!!!" << endl;
 }




int main(){

    Cat cat1;

    cat1.speak();     /*error happening here now
                     error: id returned 1 exit status*/

    return 0;
}
```

picture of errors
https://gyazo.com/bb3574ea504f2357c7ea2987facc9874

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, as it is shown.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Is this really your actual code? You didn't forget a semicolon at the end of the class definition or something like that?

Comment: this is a copy and paste copy of my code

Comment: Can you check that the Cat.h you are editing is in the same directory as Cat.cpp and you don't accidentally have an older version of Cat.h in that directory instead?

Comment: give me a few minutes im making a quick video clip.

Comment: The other thing to try is to temporarily replace the line `#include "Cat.h"` in both files with the entire contents of Cat.h and see if the problem still happens. That will narrow it down to a code problem or an include problem.

Comment: The code as written is [working as intended](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8GnfKteRt5XA5uBo).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqvQivVfAdI

Comment: @newToCpp Try adding a line to the .h file, `#error This` and then see if *both* cpp files now show an error on the line in cat.h. If not, you have spurious files as TheDark is fishing for.

Comment: Please communicate in writing. Video chat is not efficient for describing reproducible technical problems, not to speak of the uselessness for the community in the future.

Comment: i added #error This inside Cat.h and the other 2 files didnt do anything differantly

Comment: if its working on melpon, then why might it not work on my program o.o

Comment: If you copy it all into the one file (in the right order) and _that_ works, then it's likely a problem with your includes. Could be an [idiosyncrasy of `#include ""` in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.110).aspx) (if you're using VS)

Comment: ill try this, && I am using Code::Blocks 16.01

Comment: do you think it made a differance since i made a header file, then a source file? rather than just a class?

Comment: No, the order wouldn't matter. As long as the .cpp files can find the .h file via the #include directive you will be fine. What happened when you copy+pasted it all into a single file? Did it work?

Comment: when i put them all together it gives me the same error

Comment: if i put  the header over the cat.cpp then it returns a different error under the original main.cpp

_undefined referend to Cat::Cat()_---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




**int main(){

    Cat cat1;

    cat1.speak(); //error is here now

    return 0;
}**

Comment: Can you add the entire code as it looked when you put it together? One more thing to look at, it is possible your Cat.h contains a non-ascii character in the declaration that means that "Cat" doesn't match "Cat". This would explain why it works when you paste it here. You could try retyping parts of it, or cutting and pasting from what is here.

Comment: i went ahead and added it to the main post at the bottom

Comment: Thank you "The Dark" between you and the best answer below, i have been able to fix my bug and i cant thank you enough!!! I've been working on this since yesterday. I'm not 100% sure why it wasn't working but its up and running now. :) I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: id returned 1 exit status

No. The actual error is

```
undefined reference to Cat::Cat()
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is no any "id" which can return any exit status.  There is ld, which is a linker. Its job is to create the executable file, after your files are compiled. It takes all your compiled files, and links them together. If there is a function which you call in your files, but it is not defined in your files, the linker searches for it in standard libraries, or in any additional libraries which you provided, and adds the function (and functions it calls) to your executable.

Here the problem is, you implicitly call for constructor for your class Cat, and you declare it, but you hadn't provide it.  Obviously, the linker cannot find constructor for your class in standard libraries.

There are two ways to deal with it. One is to provide the constructor, i.e.

```
Cat::Cat() {
}
```

Alternatively, you may remove the line

```
Cat();
```

from your code. In this case, the default constructor will be generated authomatically.  (For each class, the constructor without parameters is authomatically generated, unless any constructor is provided.)

Comment: It's likely OP just added this from [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336187/4143855) and it wasn't part of the original problem; however, it's hard to say as this whole thing has just become a mess.

Comment: @Tas I respond to the text as it is now.  I cannot respond to historical versions of his code. :)

Comment: Tbh I'm not 100% sure what fixed this after fiddling with everything all the helpful people on this fourm gave me advice to do. The Dark told me to put everything in one file, and i did. but before i attempted this i recreated the code to the full version you see at the bottom of my post. althought that didnt work, but the recreated code had the Cat(); so as per user31264's suggestion, i removed that and it worked fine in one file. next i proceeded to put them back into their classes and headers and after getting everything correct again. IT WORKED!!! SO I WANT TO THANK EVERYONE FOR HELPING!!!

Answer (score -4):

You need to add the constructor and destructor for your class Cat.

In the header for a quick fix you could do: 
Cat(){}
~Cat(){}

Comment: im sorry im extremely new and that sounds confusing to me. i would do
class Cat(){};?

Thanks for your quick response tho.

Comment: The compiler generates a default constructor and destructor for you if you don't explicitly provide any.

Comment: Don't know why my answer got down voted so much. Turns out I was right.